# Let custom text widget use the same font as the theme

Tags: themes, formatting, widget-text, fonts

On this page, I have created a text widget. I don't know how to match this up with the font on the rest of the site. The theme uses the Playfair Display font. I don't have extensive knowledge of Wordpress yet so apologies if this is a frustrating question. 
Here is the link http://croiativefilms.com/about-me-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: You just have to put this code in your custom-css area in the wordpress customizer:

```
.wpb_wrapper {font-family: playfair display;}
```

But this will affect all items on your site with the CSS-Class ".wpb_wrapper" so maybe you should look for a way to specifice the CSS-Classes and CSS-IDs for single elements of your page if you have to, so that you're able to specify your CSS-Code, when you need some like now, to point just at the one specified Element.

Comment: Thanks @henning Bu
So would it be
`.cssclassoftextblockt { font-family: playfair display font;}`

Comment: I've updated my answer :)
If it's the solution for your problem so please mark my answer :)